# Add a column indicating whether at least one matching value exists across multiple columns

Tags: r, dataframe

I am attempting to select a number of ICD-10 medical codes from a diagnosis variable to retrieve a set of specific diagnoses within a dataset, however am having a very challenging time doing so in a succinct manner.

For context, there are over 50 different diagnostic instances for every participant ID (PID), each coded as Disease_code_1 , Disease_code_2 , Disease_code_3, etc. with corresponding dates as shown below.

```r
df = data.frame(ID = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005),
                Disease_code_1 = c('I802', 'G200','I802',NA, 'H356'),
                Disease_code_2 = c('A071',NA,'G20',NA,'I802'),
                Disease_code_3 = c('H250', NA,NA,NA,NA),
                Date_of_diagnosis_1 = c('12/06/1997','13/06/1997','14/02/2003',NA,'18/03/2005'),
                Date_of_diagnosis_2 = c('12/06/1998',NA,'18/09/2001',NA,'12/07/1993'),
                Date_of_diagnosis_3 = c('17/09/2010',NA,NA,NA,NA))

    ID Disease_code_1 Disease_code_2 Disease_code_3 Date_of_diagnosis_1 Date_of_diagnosis_2 Date_of_diagnosis_3
1 1001           I802           A071           H250          12/06/1997          12/06/1998          17/09/2010
2 1002           G200           <NA>           <NA>          13/06/1997                <NA>                <NA>
3 1003           I802            G20           <NA>          14/02/2003          18/09/2001                <NA>
4 1004           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>                <NA>                <NA>                <NA>
5 1005           H356           I802           <NA>          18/03/2005          12/07/1993                <NA>
```

As can be seen I have several `I802` codes within disease_code_1, but also within disease_code2 that I want to include in my analysis.

However, when I combine these variables that I am wanting to select together using a simple `ifelse` function, I cannot use an 'or' operator as I get 0 participants

```r
data$diagnosis<- with(data, ifelse((data$disease_code_1 == "I802||G200||H356"),1,0))
data$diagnosis[is.na(data$diagnosis)] <- 0
sum(data$diagnosis)
```

I am left with a sum of 0. The only way I can achieve a number so far is using a long format. Although there are only 3 instances and 3 disease codes in this code, there are over 50 instances and approximately 12 diagnoses that need to be counted for each, meaning this line of code becomes exceptionally long and I would like to make it more succinct.

```r
data$diagnosis <- with(data, ifelse(((data$disease_code_1 == "I802")|(data$disease_code_1 == "G200")|(data$disease_code_1 == "H356")|(data$disease_code_2 == "I802")|(data$disease_code_2 == "G200")|(data$disease_code_2 == "H356")|(data$disease_code_3 == "I802")|(data$disease_code_3 == "G200")|(data$disease_code_3 == "H356")), 1, 0))
data$diagnosis[is.na(data$diagnosis)] <- 0
sum(data$diagnosis)
```

This method will provide an answer, however once I get to a certain length, the line will also cease to run, resulting in a `+` symbol within the command line.

Is there a way I can make this much more succinct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few notes regarding your codes:

1. When you use `with`, you no longer need the `data$` syntax, just `with(data, ifelse(disease_code_1 == "I802||G200||H356"),1,0)` is enough
2. We cannot use `==` to compare a set of strings
3. In your code you have lower-case `disease_code` but in your `data` you have upper-case `Disease_code`

---

### Solution

To check the existence of a set of strings, we can use the `%in%` operator, and we can use `apply` to iterate over the rows of the data frame.

```r
data$diagnosis <- apply(data[startsWith(colnames(data), "Disease_code_")], 1, \(x) as.integer(any(x %in% c("I802", "G200", "H356"))))

    ID Disease_code_1 Disease_code_2 Disease_code_3 Date_of_diagnosis_1 Date_of_diagnosis_2 Date_of_diagnosis_3 diagnosis
1 1001           I802           A071           H250          12/06/1997          12/06/1998          17/09/2010         1
2 1002           G200           <NA>           <NA>          13/06/1997                <NA>                <NA>         1
3 1003           I802            G20           <NA>          14/02/2003          18/09/2001                <NA>         1
4 1004           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>                <NA>                <NA>                <NA>         0
5 1005           H356           I802           <NA>          18/03/2005          12/07/1993                <NA>         1
```

```
sum(data$diagnosis)
[1] 4
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dplyr::if_any()` with an assist from `tidyr::replace_na()`. As suggested by @jared_mamrot, you can use `+` to coerce the resulting logical vector to integer.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data %>%
  mutate(diagnosis = replace_na(
    +if_any(starts_with("disease_code"), \(x) x %in% c("I802", "G200", "H356")),
    0
  ))
```

Alternatively, omit the `+` and just keep as a logical vector. You’ll still be able to do arithmetic operations, plus use it directly in logical tests (i.e., `ifelse(diagnosis, ...)` rather than `ifelse(diagnosis == 1, ...)`).

Comment: This is how I would tackle it, but I probably wouldn't use `if_else()` for a "0 or 1" outcome; this should give you the same result: `data %>% mutate(diagnosis = +if_any(starts_with("Disease_"), ~.x %in% c("I802","G200","H356")))`

Comment: Neat, I’d never thought of using `+` to coerce to integer!

Answer (score 1):

The way I would approach this is to convert your original data frame into a long format and then select the rows from there:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df = data.frame(ID = c(1001, 1002, 1003, 1004, 1005),
                Disease_code_1 = c('I802', 'G200','I802',NA, 'H356'),
                Disease_code_2 = c('A071',NA,'G20',NA,'I802'),
                Disease_code_3 = c('H250', NA,NA,NA,NA),
                Date_of_diagnosis_1 = c('12/06/1997','13/06/1997','14/02/2003',NA,'18/03/2005'),
                Date_of_diagnosis_2 = c('12/06/1998',NA,'18/09/2001',NA,'12/07/1993'),
                Date_of_diagnosis_3 = c('17/09/2010',NA,NA,NA,NA))

#convert to long format, all Disease codes in one column
dflong<- pivot_longer(df, -ID, names_sep = "_(?=\\d)", names_to=c(".value", "count"), values_to= "value")

#find the rows that matches the code(s) of interest
hascondition <- which(dflong$Disease_code %in% c("I802", "G200", "H356"))

#get a list of patient IDs
patients <- unique(dflong$ID[hascondition])
length(patients)
#[1] 4

#filter/subset the original data frame
subset <- df %>% filter(ID %in% patients)
```

Answer (score 0):

In `data.table`:

```r
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[ , diagnosis := +any(.SD %in% c("I802", "G200", "H356")), 
              .(ID), ## or seq_len(NROW(df)
                .SDcols = names(df)[grep("Disease_code", names(df))]][]
```

```
#>      ID Disease_code_1 Disease_code_2 Disease_code_3 Date_of_diagnosis_1
#> 1: 1001           I802           A071           H250          12/06/1997
#> 2: 1002           G200           <NA>           <NA>          13/06/1997
#> 3: 1003           I802            G20           <NA>          14/02/2003
#> 4: 1004           <NA>           <NA>           <NA>                <NA>
#> 5: 1005           H356           I802           <NA>          18/03/2005
#>    Date_of_diagnosis_2 Date_of_diagnosis_3 diagnosis
#> 1:          12/06/1998          17/09/2010         1
#> 2:                <NA>                <NA>         1
#> 3:          18/09/2001                <NA>         1
#> 4:                <NA>                <NA>         0
#> 5:          12/07/1993                <NA>         1
```